# Infinite volume gain of the whole universe due to curvature of spacetime from a finite mass?

Tags: general-relativity, curvature

The volume in curved space of a spherically symmetric metric calculates as
$$V_{prop}=4 \pi \int_{0}^{R} r^2\sqrt{g_{rr}(r,\alpha)}dr$$

where $g_{rr}(r,\alpha)$ is the rr - component of the metric tensor and $\alpha\equiv 2GM/c^2$

The "normal volume" in Minkowski spacetime is

$$V_{norm}=4 \pi \int_{0}^{R} r^2dr$$

The difference between $V_{prop}$ and $V_{norm}$ is
$$\Delta V = V_{prop}-V_{norm}$$

$$\Delta V = 4 \pi \int_{0}^{R} r^2\sqrt{g_{rr}}dr - 4 \pi \int_{0}^{R} r^2dr$$

$$\Delta V = 4 \pi \int_{0}^{R} r^2\left(\sqrt{g_{rr}}-1\right)dr$$

Lets take the (exterior) Schwarzschild-metric and Schwarzschild-coordinates $t, r, \phi, \theta$. Therein, $g_{rr} $ is always larger than 1, therefore:
$$\Delta V = 4 \pi \int_{0}^{R} r^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1} {1-\frac{\alpha}{r}} }-1\right)dr$$

The integral for $\Delta V$ will diverge, I suppose, if R runs to infinity.

1. Is that right? (This essentially comes down to the question whether $\int r^2\sqrt{g_{rr}}dr$ diverges faster then $\int r^2 dr$)
2. Is the interpretation right, that the volume gain of the whole universe due to a finite mass is infinite?
3. In Quantum mechanics, the space itself possesses some energy. Can this be understood as infinite energy is added already through a finite mass?

Comment: Note that the calculation of volume is *coordinate dependent*. Another point: the fact the integral diverges for $R \rightarrow \infty$ doesn't mean much, as so does this integral for Minkowski space in certain coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the note! Yes, it is coordinate dependent. Let's try (for simplicity and homogeneity) the Schwarzschild-metric. If it diverges there, then it diverges in any metric. Furthermore, I tried to make the question clearer with an edit and emphasis on $\Delta V$

Comment: Does not $$g_{rr}=(1-\alpha/r)^{-1} $$ converge to $1$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$, making the integrand converge to zero?  This would cause the $\Delta V$ to converge to a finite value.

Comment: @RC_23 in the integrand, as $R \rightarrow \infty$, $r^2$ will diverge faster then the $\sqrt{g_{rr} } - 1$ - term converges to zero. Therefore, the whole integrand will diverge

Comment: I think the question might be ill posed, because you are essentially trying to find the value of $\infty-\infty$.  Before you factored $r^2$ out of the integrand, the equation was the subtraction of two separate integrals known to be infinite on their own. I'm not an expert in the mathematics in this area, but this is my suggestion to consider.

Comment: The term $\infty - \infty$ is not converging to zero for every case. (simple example: $e^x-x$ will diverge). In the above case, it's also for the form $\infty - \infty$(I'll add that) , that the second $\infty$ does not compensate the growth of the first.

Comment: @MartyMcFly yes, it does diverge, but you're looking at the volume of a region in the limit of infinite radius, so why would you expect it *not* to? My point about coordinate dependence is that I don't think this calculation reveals anything physical.

Answer (score 0):

One remark: your integral should consider two parts of metric, the interior and the exterior one:
$$\Delta V = 4 \pi \int_{0}^{R} r^2\left(\frac{1} {\sqrt{1-r_{S}/R^3~r^2}}-1\right)dr+4 \pi \int_{R}^{r} r^2\left(\frac{1} {\sqrt{1-r_{S}/r}}-1\right)dr$$
For asymptotic behavior only the second integral is important. For great $r$, or equivalently for small $r_{S}/r$, it behaves like $$\Delta V_{2} \sim 4\pi \Bigg(\frac{1}{4}~r_{S}~(r^2-R^2)+\frac{3}{8}~r_{}^2~(r-R)+\frac{15}{16}~r_{S}^3~\log(r/R)~+~...)\Bigg) $$

Ad. 1: Yes, for $r$ running to infinity $\Delta V$ will diverge.

Ad. 2: No, the presence of finite energy density is a *conditio sin qua non* of the emergence of universe and a static asymptotically flat universe is infinite per definition.

Ad. 3: No, spacetime posses no energy. One can maybe say, that the energy needed to "warp" spacetime is equal to the energy density (stress-energy tensor) of matter there.

Comment: Why is "the presence of finite energy density a conditio sin qua non of the emergence of universe"? How about the trivial solution of empty space without any matter in it?

Comment: Regarding Ad. 3: Why does spacetime posses no energy? At least the cosmological constant $\Lambda$ would lead to a nonzero energy density of the vacuum, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MartyMcFly, please read this article https://medium.com/@rloldershaw/einstein-without-matter-there-is-no-space-or-time-c2357c75286b (your first question). Cosmological constant is a kind of matter with constant energy density due to due to some quantum field. It is my view.

Comment: But it leads to space producing _more_ space and so forth... So how could it have a constant energy density? Wouldn't that contradict energy conservation?

Comment: Interesting link, thank you!

Comment: Hence, I found that citation also in nature, there, however, characterized as "partly joking" to the non-physicist: https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-018-05004-4

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be more serious source. If we talk about spacetime we have to precise which situation we mean, static solution or  non static. The last one deals with the „Big Bang“. Our considerations have dealt with a „toy“ universe described by some static solution. The true universe started with some finite amount of energy density by infinite pressure and expands since then. Such universe is not infinite, I suppose.